# Difference between `DETERMINISTIC`, `READS SQL DATA` and `NO SQL` in MySQL functions

Tags: mysql, function, deterministic

I have been working in a project where I have to create functions in MySQL. But it's been hard for me to find the proper difference between `DETERMINISTIC`,  `READS SQL DATA` and `NO SQL`.

I also read in one of the posts that `DETERMINISTIC` has been misused a lot, so I want to have a clear idea before I use them.

Comment: So what is your question exactly?

Comment: I want to know what when to set 'DETERMINISTIC' AND/OR 'READS SQL DATA' AND/OR 'NO SQL' while creating MySQL functions.